# PHPUnit: what does 'Attribute' refer to?

Tags: phpunit

Sorry if this is a rudimentary question, but what does the term 'Attribute' refer to in the context of PHPUnit testing? I know what properties and methods are, I know what public/private/protected do. I know the different between static and instance variables. But I see all these 'Attribute' oriented asserts in the PHPUnit command sets but none of the documentation I have seems to take the step back to describe what 'attribute' is actually referring to. properties? methods? all of the above???

SW

Answer (score 2):

Properties.

The assertAttribute metods are used to test public and [private properties](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html) of a class or object.

```
class Foo {
    private $bar = 'baz';
}

class fooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    // ...
    public function testFooAttibute(){
        $this->assertAttributeEquals(
          'baz',  /* expected value */
          'bar',  /* attribute name */
          new Foo /* object         */
        );
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class something
{
   public $i_m = 'attribute';

   public function i_m_method()
   {

   }

}
```

More to read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: "I know what properties and methods are, I know what public/private/protected do" not a helpful answer.

Comment: Connect the dots. If you know what are atributes and there are assertions to test attributes. What do you think they are for?

Comment: I agree with you @Endijs but mate you should have elaborated. thanks

Comment: silly question perhaps, but why didn't they just call it assertProperty* ?